# How to access elements in a SimpleXMLElement object?

Tags: php, object, simplexml

I have an object name result.

When I use this code:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

It shows the result:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
([error_code] => 00
[token] => 100091-3d43a321ab697aeef32e8aaa21579c5f
[payment_type] => 2
[transaction_id] => 19634669)
```

When I use this code:

```
echo $result['token'];
```

It shows nothing. How can I access the value in `$result['token']`?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1415724).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: Don't use `print_r($result);` with SimpleXML, use `echo $result->asXML();`, looks like it should be `echo $result->token;`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is somewhat incomplete. So I'm assuming `$result` is your simplexmlobject  But here you go

```
echo $result->token
```